# jQuery - Show variable, not text string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, variables, escaping

I have a variable being set as the `.html();` of a `<div />`

The variable is the name of another variable. I want it to display the contents of the other variable, however it simply displays the name of the other variable.

How can I force it to show the variable contents rather than just a literal text string?

```
var clothing = 'dogeshop cryptoshop doge_clothing fyrstikken the_molly_machine peace_and_love moolah_market shibe_swag undieguys urban_graff kravshop got_doge mean_elephant the_dogedoor_store';


setInterval( function() {
    var term = $("input").val();
    $("#results").html(term);
}, 100);
```

*When the user types 'clothing' into `$("input");` the contents of the 'clothing' variable should be displayed in the `$("#results");` `<div />`. Instead it just says 'clothing'.*

Comment: I don't think this is the right mechanism. Why not use an associative array instead of a variable? So you'd look up the string `'clothing'` (obtained from `$("input").val()`) and retrieve `'dogeshop cryptoshop...'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use object properties, like this

```
var obj = {};
obj.clothing = 'dogeshop cryptoshop doge_clothing fyrstikken the_molly_machine peace_and_love moolah_market shibe_swag undieguys urban_graff kravshop got_doge mean_elephant the_dogedoor_store';


setInterval( function() {
    var term = $("input").val();
    $("#results").html(obj[term]);
}, 100);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZL7EQ/

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to solve this is using `eval`:

```
$("#results").html(eval(term))
```

But you really [shouldn't want to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea). :)

Comment: @rla4, @william44isme using `eval()` on a user input is a big security issue!!

Comment: Just edited my answer and added a link explaining why not. Just keep in mind that it has many pitfalls and use it wisely

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary.

```
// store strings in an object so you can look them up by key
var dict = {
    clothing: 'dogeshop ...',
    anotherKey: '...'
};

// update the result when the input changes
$('input').on('change', function() {
    var result = dict[this.value]; // make sure the key exists

    if (result) {
        $('#results').val(result); // update the results
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow! This is fantastic, thanks for optimising the code by removing that interval too.

Answer (score 0):

I use to make this mistake myself when working with jQuery.

Try instead:

```
 $("#results").text(term);
```

Not sure what you have the interval for. You could just change the `#results` with a change event.

Comment: results.text not html :)

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it still doesn't seem to work. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LyQqg/)

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp , it shows the why and how. I know it works for the code, I took it from my own work. Let me try what you have there.  And Also your interval event , look to the next answer for the ON event

Comment: @alexmac you are misinterpreting the problem. It's not about setting the contents of the `div`; the issue is that the string _clothing_ is being printed instead of the __contents of the variable `clothing`__.